# Doubts in Using CustomListView

Tags: android, listview

I just created a ListView, the itemclickevent works fine with it. But when i add a combox box to the list view, the focus goes within the selected object list in the object only, but cannot get the click event, but i can check or uncheck the checkBox.

Any Ideas how to use this? I want the click event for selected object as well as the check box.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understand your question correctly. But if you want to get a itemClickedEvent for a listview Item at the moment the user checks a checkbox this is not easily possible.

The Checkbox will handle the press on it and because the event is handled the list won't get the information. You can try to set the clickable of the checkbox to false and check and uncheck the box yourself at the moment the user clicks the listitem.